# Какие есть инструменты для быстрой миграции данных?

Tags: база-данных, поиск-программ, миграция

Под миграцией я понимаю перекидывание данных из одного место хранения в другое.

Например, залить CSV в MS SQL. Слить данные из MS SQL в MySQL.

Да, в состав SSMS входит бесплатная утилита для миграцией, но она крайне медленно работает на больших объемах данных(Похоже, что вставка идет по 1 записи).

Есть ESFMigrationToolKit, но он дорогой.

Какие еще есть инструменты, которые могут решить мою задачу? В приоритете бесплатные решения, но платные тоже можете указать с явной пометкой, что она платная.

Минимум, что я хочу переносить- это таблицу из одного источника в другой.

Comment: Уточните в заголовке вопроса и в теле, что именно вы хотите мигрировать, какого рода сущности?

Comment: @Kromster добавил. Минимум это таблицы.

Comment: Почти все что нашел - коммерческое, с примерно таким же прайсом. Но есть вот это http://www.sqlines.com/download

Comment: Еще MySQL Workbench через ODBC: `Database` > `Migration Wizard`. Есть Generic RDBMS, MSSQL, Posrgres, Sybase, SQLite

Comment: @TotalPusher CSVшек не хватает=(